# How does std::string's c_str() function return null-terminating string?

Tags: c++, string, stdstring, null-terminated, c-str

I cannot understand if char * returned from string.c_str() points to the same buffer (and not making any copy) how is it null terminated? does the function add null-terminator in the end of string? and what happens if buffer doesn't have any extra bytes to store it?

thanks.

Comment: C++ strings are always null-terminated, cf. http://eel.is/c++draft/string.classes#basic.string-4

Comment: The buffer *has* an extra byte to hold the terminator, always. In theory it could store the terminator value only when you ask to see it, but in practice it is always there.

Comment: if null terminator is always there it means that string.data() is EXACTLY the same as string.c_str()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++11, strings are null-terminated internally, and [both `c_str()` and `data()` return the same thing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

Comment: are they? ... if I write string s = "mda" is that internally interpreted as 'm'+'d'+'a'+'/0'?

Comment: @შოთასილაგაძე Yes: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal